# WCF REST returing always XML by default

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I have a WCF Service defined on a .svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="OL4RENT.WebService.BienWSREST" CodeBehind="BienWSREST.svc.cs"  Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

The interface:

```
  [WebeInvoke( Method = "GET",
  ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
  UriTemplate = "/{tipo}/{bienId}")]
  DataBien VerBien(string tipo, string bienId);
```

So it should return Json by default but if I do a normal request via browser, I get the response in xml format! I only get Json if the request has Content-Type = application/json.

How do I configure the default behaviour to return json?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx): If the request message contains an Accept header the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) infrastructure searches for a type that it supports.

Browsers by default add a lot of stuff to the Accept header of each request. See http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers for more information about that. 
Bottom line is that the browser you are using has "application/xml" before "application/json" (if it even has it) in the header, thus causing WCF internals to return an XML.

It is better if you use a rest client (e.g. Fiddler, RESTClient extension for Chrome or FF) to test your service calls.

See [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx) regarding how to configure how WCF svcs behave for the requests.

Comment: Strange, i have another project returing json as default, with same configuration :S